# Can anyone explain to me the difference between .toSting and .string in Java?

Tags: java

I want to know the difference between .toString and .string , i know the term .toString and have been using it since last 1 year but i recently came upon .string and curious to know about it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such method named `.string()` in Java's "standard library".

But, it could some external library and/or framework having `.string()` in their API. One of this example of such method is the `.string()` method in the `ResponseBody` of OkHttp API.

Comment: Yeah thanks , now i get it , it was used in the Response Body of the OkHttp API and i was confused about it. Now  its clear.